# Photos Map of a place on Instagram

Tags: geotag, instagram

Is there a method to display the photos map of a specific place posted on instagram?
For example, i would to realize a photos map of my town Pietragalla with all photos posted on Instagram from all users (Tag on instagram: (Pietragalla - Pz).

Comment: What GIS software are you using?  What have you tried?

Comment: I'm using QGIS. I haven't tried because i don't know how export coordinates from geotagged photos on Instagram

Comment: It sounds like your question should be "How to export coordinates from geotagged photos on Instagram?"  There is an [edit] button beneath your question that you can use to revise it.  Once that has been answered you'll be able to move on to trying to display that data in QGIS (or elsewhere), and ask a new question if you get stuck again.

Answer (score 2):

The geotag information is held in the exif data of the photo. In QGIS, you need not extract this but can use the [Photo2Shape](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/photo2shape/) plugin (go `Plugins->Manage and install plugins` and then type 'photo' in the search box and click install) or perhaps better still the [Intagram2Qgis](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/instagram2qgis/) plugin!